# Bluetooth doesn't work with Ubuntu 18.04 [BCM20702A1-13d3-3411]

Tags: drivers, 18.04, bluetooth, ubuntu-drivers

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 in my Alienware 17, everything is running fine except the Bluetooth. It's active but I can't connect with my headphones, telephone and mouse.

`sudo dmesg | grep -i bluetooth`

```
[    4.733843] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.733970] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.733973] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.733975] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.733979] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.941900] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 63
[    4.942900] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x07
[    4.958903] Bluetooth: hci0: kacub18pc
[    4.959898] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 0000
[    4.960174] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-13d3-3411.hcd failed with error -2
[    4.960176] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM20702A1-13d3-3411.hcd not found
[    6.157166] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.157167] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    6.157171] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   30.844116] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   30.844120] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   30.844125] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   75.236262] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[   88.291313] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  107.311359] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try executing the following command in the terminal.

This will download the [Broadcom Bluetooth firmware for Linux kernel](https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware#broadcom-bluetooth-firmware-for-linux-kernel) to `/lib/firmware/brcm`.

```
sudo wget --tries=3 --timeout=120 https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/raw/master/brcm/BCM20702A1-13d3-3411.hcd -P /lib/firmware/brcm
```

After installing the firmware, simply reboot to load the driver.